# How to download given dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am running Gradle builds in a Docker container and I wanted to create a Docker image that would already contain all most common dependencies, so the build itself does not need to download them.

Is there an easy way to tell Gradle to download particular library (or plugin) with all dependencies without a specific build file? I want to use the image to run different builds that do not share any configuration.

I am looking for something similar to Maven's `dependency:get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solutions other than creating a small build script in Gradle with some dependencies defined there and running build command.

However, it was easier to just mount Gradle cache as a volume in the container I was using. That has added benefit of being reusable accross many Docker containers. This is the approach I ended up using, if anyone is interested.